# Electron, Closing "sub-window" from main window

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a `main.js` file and a `add.js`, when I click on a button that's in the menu of `main.js` the second file is called like this:

```
const mainMenuTemplate = [
 {
  label: 'File',
  submenu: [
      {   
          label: 'Add',
          click(){  //Calling add.js and the function createAddWindow()
                    let add = require( __dirname + '/add.js'); add.createAddWindow(); }   
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

(This is a simplified version of the actual menu, but the rest is not important)

Now, in `add.js` I call a html where I use an input, this input is send to `main.js` like this

```
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
        ipcRenderer.send('item:add',item);
    }

</script>
```

The problem is that when I "hear" that event in `main.js` I would like to close the 'add' window but I can't do it like this

```
ipcMain.on('item:add',function(event, item){
  console.log(item);
  mainWindow.webContents.send('item:add',item);
  add.close();
});
```

Because of course, `add` is not defined here. How can I do this?.

I know that I can merge both files into one, but is that a better practice and I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance. I know is quite a long question but I just want to make everything as clear as possible.

Comment: So you just want to close the window created by `createAddWindow()`? (first, it would help to show that code). Do you know the `id` of that window? If you do, you can fetch the window by the id and call `close` on it.

Comment: In that function I just create a window, but how can I get the id?

Comment: You can just do `win.id`. When you close that window, you can do `BrowserWindow.fromId(id).close();`. Can you access that window from `submitForm`? If so, then send the id as an argument. What does `createAddWindow` look like? Alternatively, consider having that function return the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of ideas

1) Keep track of the newly added windows in the main process.

```
const ADD_WINDOW_ID = 'ADD_WINDOW'
const windows = {}

// make the window

windows[ADD_WINDOW_ID] = new BrowserWindow() // ...
```

In the `close:add` IPC event on the main process, close the add window:

```
if (windows[ADD_WINDOW_ID]) {
    windows[ADD_WINDOW_ID].close()
}
```

2) use `webContents` api to get all web contents for this electron app

*This is not a complete solution, perhaps investigate*

Each window has a webContents uniquely identified, from the add window, look up the id of the current web contents, and pass that to the IPC callback:

```
    // add window
    import { remote } from 'electron'
    const { id } = remote.getCurrentWebContents()
```

In the main process

```
import { webContents } from 'electron'
// on the IPC callback, identify which web contents
const allWebContents = webContents.getAllWebContents()
// todo: find the web contents with the right id, close the window
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sub-window was set as a child window try this: set your parent window to a const and use the getChildWindows() method on that and console.log your child window.  You will see that there is no 'close' method on the child window.  Using the 'hide' method does work.